# Change color of NSTextField

Tags: swift, cocoa, nstextfield

I'm trying to code an easy example to modify the color of a NSTextfield playing with green and red colors as good answer or wrong.
I cannot achieve that cause i always obtained an error message when using this apple guide page for NSTextField, [AppKit framework ref.](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSTextField_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSTextField/setTextColor:)

I'm trying to use this code :

```
@IBOutlet weak var mensajeResultado: NSTextField! 

when trying to colorize it without success
let rango = NSRange(location: 0,length: 0)
        mensajeResultado.superclass.setTextColor(NSColor.redColor(), range: rango)
```

Comment: You are saying change the color over a range of 0 length? it's doing just what you asked it to do.

Comment: the method proposed by Xcode use a second argument for range, but in the apple doc there is an unique input, NSColor. That's weird.

Comment: you can't use NSRange(location: 0,length: 0) on a String

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Shouldn't it just be:

```
mensajeResultado.textColor = NSColor.redColor()
```

?

Comment: How is this not an answer? I'm not 100% certain, since I don't use Swift, so I phrased it as a question, but it is intended as a (possible) answer.

Comment: My apologies, that one was a mistake on my part. I've removed my comment and upvoted.

Comment: FWIW it's `NSColor.red` these days.

Answer (score 7):

**Ken Thomases' answer is right**, you just have to assign the color to the `textColor` property of your text field.

Just for info, it's very convenient to test in a Playground when you're not sure, for example:

```
import Cocoa
import XCPlayground

let tf = NSTextField(frame: NSMakeRect(50, 50, 100, 100))
tf.stringValue = "test"
tf.font = NSFont(name: "Helvetica", size: 16)
tf.backgroundColor = NSColor.blueColor()

tf.textColor = NSColor.whiteColor()

let v = NSView(frame: NSMakeRect(0, 0, 200, 200))
v.addSubview(tf)

XCPShowView("My View", v)
```

[image: playground]

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I didn't know i can test UI parts in the playground. That open a new way of work to me. Thanks againt.